# Where do I reload a tableView from the choice of a UIAlertController?

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

I have a `UITableView` with some swipe actions. One of them presents an action sheet via `UIAlertController`, and lets the user change category of a `UITableViewCell`, making the cell appear in another section.

What I try to achieve is to reload the tableView after the choice has been made, but it seems like the alert is called asynchronously. Can someone help me understand the call stack and where to put the `tableview.reloadData()` call?

```swift
        let switchTypeAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: nil) { [weak self] (_,_,success) in

            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Change type", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
            for type in orderItem.orderItemType.allValues where type != item.type {
                ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "\(type.prettyName)", style: .default, handler: self?.handleChangeType(item: item, type: type)))
            }
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))
            self?.present(ac, animated: true)
            tableview.reloadData()
            success(true)
        }

    func handleChangeType(item: orderItem, type: orderItem.orderItemType) -> (_ alertAction:UIAlertAction) -> (){
        return { alertAction in
            item.type = type
        }
    }
```

I would assume that the calls were being executed in this order, but when debugging I see that `self?.present(ac, animated: true)` are actually extecuted after the block, so the reload and the success response are executed first. Does this have anything to do with the closure being `@escaping?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `UIAlertController` are "async", in that the VC that presents the alert will still run code, while the alert is presented. In fact this is generally true for any VC presenting another VC.

You should call `reloadData` in the `handler` closure that `UIAlertAction.init` accepts. That's the closure that will be called when the user selects the action. Here, you are passing the return value of `handleChangeType`, so you should write it here:

```
func handleChangeType(item: orderItem, type: orderItem.orderItemType) -> (_ alertAction:UIAlertAction) -> (){
    return { alertAction in
        item.type = type
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

If you know the index paths of to and from which the item is moved, you can use `moveTow(at:to:)` instead to only reload those two rows, instead of *everything*.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but it still doesn't reload my table (Visually, I see that the code gets executed.. Should the reloadData rebuild the whole view? :( And yes, I know I could use move, but I'm building the sections dynamically, creating only those that have corresponding rows in the table..

Comment: @perage try putting a breakpoint in the closure, does `reloadData` actually get called

Comment: It would also help if you can show more code @perage For example, where does `item` come from in the `self?.handleChangeType(item: item, type: type)` line? How did you implement the table view data source?

Comment: It gets called yes. The item comes from `let item = sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]` inside `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt`. When dismissing the ViewController and opening it again, everything has been reloaded as it should - but it doesn't happen when I call it inside the closure :( 
Could it be that the tableView is not avilable inside the closure? I tried to get the swiped row with `if let index = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow `but that ended up as as not setting the index...

Comment: Debugging, I see that my sections struct are only computed at first load, the next ones, it uses the saved property. How can I make it compute each time and not used the saved array

` var sections: [SectionData] = {
  var sections = [SectionData]()
  for type in orderItem.orderItemType.allValues {
   let items = Cart.sharedInstance.order.items.filter { $0.type == type }
   if !items.isEmpty {
    sections.append(SectionData(type: type, data: items))
   }
  }
  return sections
 }()`

Comment: @perage Okay, so the problem is you didn't reload your model... Write a method `reloadModel` that re-computes `sections`, and call it before you call `reloadData`. Simple, right?

Comment: yes! But it’s a computes property - shouldn’t it be calculated each time?

Comment: @perage It's not a computed property. Compare `var sections: [SectionData] = { ... }()` and `var sections: [SectionData] { ... }`. Your code uses the former, which is a stored property that just happens to be initialised to the result of a closure. However, I don't think a computed property is suitable here, as computing the sections seems to be an O(n) operation. As you have more items, it becomes more time consuming to compute. You wouldn't want to compute it _too_ often, would you?

Comment: Aha, thanks! Well, this is an in-store POS app, so the tableView will seldom have more than 5-7 rows, so computing it shouldn’t be a heavy task..